# Service Bus On-Prem - Abandoning deferred messages

Tags: azure, servicebus, deferred-execution, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-pack

Lately I've been working with the **Azure Pack** & **Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1** where I'm doing message deferal with queues.

I was wondering if it is possible to abandon a deferred message in order to make it visible to others again? Currently I can retrieve my deferred message by using `Receive(_seqNr)` but when I call the `Abandon()` method it has no effect.

Is there some way to achieve this behavior?

*Note that I can't use PeekLock only since the abandoning occures later in the application flow when required.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking into the same scenario - **As of this writing Abandoning deferred messages is not possible.**

Comment: Unbelievable. Huge bug. How is one supposed to handle failed processing for a deferred message with long processing time that fails? If it cannot be abandoned, there's no way to return it to the queue to be picked up for reprocessing. The only option is to destroy it by completing it, or reintroduce it to the queue with a completely new timestamp, losing the original processing date?